# I can't understand this programming code for psedorandom number generator for hashing

Tags: java

First of all I just begun learning Java and i can say it more challenging then C or python. I'm not very keen on programming to so I have hard time understanding how some codes works. This one in particular

```
public class Pseudo
 {
 final int a = 2;
 final int c = 3;
 int address;
 String list[][] = new String [100][6];



public void AddRecord(String ID, String Name, String Course, String Address, String Email, String Contact)
{        
   address = (a * Integer.parseInt(ID) + c) % list.length;

     if((Integer.parseInt(ID)<100000||Integer.parseInt(ID)>999999)||ID.length()==0 || Name.length()==0 || Course.length()==0 || Address.length()==0)
     {
        showMessageDialog(null,"The ID number should be in six digit and the particular field should not be empty","",ERROR_MESSAGE);
     }

    else{

     if(list[address][0]!=null){
        showMessageDialog(null,"Collison is occur, the same address is get. Recalculating...............","",WARNING_MESSAGE);

        while(list[address][0]!=null)
        {                
            address = (a * address + c) % list.length;               
        }
     }

        list[address][0] = ID; 
        list[address][1] = Name; 
        list[address][2] = Course; 
        list[address][3] = Address;
        list[address][4] = Email;
        list[address][5] = Contact;

        showMessageDialog(null,"Student Information " + ID + " will be saved in address: " + address,"",INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

   }
}
```

The confusion come when

```
address = (a * Integer.parseInt(ID) + c) % list.length;

     if((Integer.parseInt(ID)<100000||Integer.parseInt(ID)>999999)||ID.length()==0 || Name.length()==0 || Course.length()==0 || Address.length()==0)
```

What does it mean. From what I understand from this code is that inside an IF statement you can have more then 1 condition. I'm no very sure since this is my first time seeing such a code.

The second is this

```
   if(list[address][0]!=null){
        showMessageDialog(null,"Collison is occur, the same address is get. Recalculating...............","",WARNING_MESSAGE);

        while(list[address][0]!=null)
        {                
            address = (a * address + c) % list.length;               
        }
     }

        list[address][0] = ID; 
        list[address][1] = Name; 
        list[address][2] = Course; 
        list[address][3] = Address;
        list[address][4] = Email;
        list[address][5] = Contact;

        showMessageDialog(null,"Student Information " + ID + " will be saved in address: " + address,"",INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

If collision occurs the address of which it is stored should be altered using a psedorandom number generator again but what I can't grasped is 
list[address][0]!=null.I am just baffle with this line. I know its job is change the address if collision happens but i don't know the exact mechanics of how this part is executed.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand from this code is that inside an IF statement you can have more then 1 condition.

Well, yes and no.  You can construct complex conditions based on many smaller conditions, but ultimately the whole thing has to resolve to a single boolean true/false result.

Consider the condition in this case:

```
(Integer.parseInt(ID)<100000||Integer.parseInt(ID)>999999)||ID.length()==0 || Name.length()==0 || Course.length()==0 || Address.length()==0
```

Let's break that down into its components:

```
(
    Integer.parseInt(ID)<100000 ||
    Integer.parseInt(ID)>999999
) ||
ID.length()==0 ||
Name.length()==0 ||
Course.length()==0 ||
Address.length()==0
```

It's really just chaining together a bunch of comparisons into one big true/false statement.  You can essentially read something like this as:

> If (something) or (something else) or (another thing) then...

And each `something` can itself contain small `something`s, etc.  You can build as complex a logical condition as you want, grouping sub-conditions with parentheses, as long as the whole thing resolves to a single true/false result.

---

> what I can't grasped is list[address][0]!=null

That is just checking if a particular value is `null`.  That value is part of a nested (jagged) array.  So you have a variable called `list`.  That variable is an array.  Each element in that array is, itself, *also* an array.  So you end up with a kind of 2-dimensional array (but a jagged one, where any given sub-array doesn't have to be the same length as any other).

That specific piece of code looks into the `list` array, at the `address` index, and looks at the `0` index of *that* sub-array, and checks if that value is `null`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubts for the first part.But I'm still confuse fort he second part.This is my understanding of the code.That particular part of the code is suppose to resolve any collision if the user enters the same ID number right so shouldn't it be checking the value that's causing the collision. But the line seems to be doing is as long as a null value is detected the corresponding procedure would be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, understanding any code is much easier if it's properly formatted. All good IDEs have such a function, e.g. for Eclipse the shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+F, for IntelliJ IDEA Ctrl+Alt+L.

The most important part, which might resolve your first confusion: || is the logical OR in Java, meaning the ID must be a number between 100000 and 999999 and the attributes must not be empty. Or literally, if the ID is smaller than 100000 or larger than 999999 or any of the values are empty, there will be an error message and nothing will be done.

For the second part: `null` means that a variable is not set, so to prevent overwriting an entry you can check if it's already set, i.e. not equal to `null`. So the code changes the `address` variable until an address is found for which no data is set yet and then uses it to store the given data.

There are several potential problems in this code, among which:

- several calls to the relatively slow Integer.parseInt(String) where it could be called once and stored into a variable
- potential NumberFormatException if ID isn't a number (or is empty, or has some excess white spaces)
- potential infinite loop if the array is full

But as it looks like some CS homework it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubts for the first part.But I'm still confuse fort he second part.This is my understanding of the code.That particular part of the code is suppose to resolve any collision if the user enters the same ID number right so shouldn't it be checking the value that's causing the collision. But the line seems to be doing is as long as a null value is detected the corresponding procedure would be implemented.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what detail you are missing, I hope it's part of my explanation :) The address will be updated as long as the corresponding cell is NOT empty, i.e it's searching for an empty spot in the array. Please notice the != (means not equals) and the `address` variable on both sides of the assignment, meaning it's another value after each iteration.

Comment: Ohh now I get it.So if collision happens this line of code is going to find new address for it and that !=null is to check for empty address. Now  get it...Thank so much sorry if I'm  a bit slow.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Could you please mark an answer so the question is officially resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Thank You so much Mr David. I understand the first part where if u have a condition u can stack it on each other and from what i can understand it only  works with the  ||(OR) statement since using this will guarantee either a true or false ending.

```
while(list[address][0]!=null)
```

But I'm still a little confuse for part 2 of my problem. Since that line is to check the array is null meaning no value right.This is my understanding of the situation.That particular part of the code is suppose to resolve any collision if the user enters the same ID number right so shouldn't it be checking the value that's causing the collision. But the line seems to be doing is as long as a null value is detected the corresponding procedure would be implemented.